# Why is Toyohisa OK with Olmine contributing to the fight, but not Jeanne dArc?

Tags: drifters

In episode 7, in the well, Toyohisa tells Jeanne to go home and act like a woman after he determines that she is a woman.  However, he was OK with Olmine providing support through magic spells.

Why is Toyohisa OK with Olmine contributing to the fight, but not Jeanne?  Is it the manner in which they contribute?  Is spellcasting OK, but fighting with a sword not OK?

Answer (score 2):

You have to keep in mind that Toyohisa comes from Feudal Japan (16th Century) where armies are comprised of solely men, and where the social structure basically forbids Women anywhere near a battlefield.

Having a Woman fighting him to the death breaks his "code of conduct", and what was "socially acceptable" for him, which is why he told Jeanne to basically go back to the kitchen.

There are two main reasons as to why Olmine was not treated the same by Toyohisa:

1. She saved his life (at the start of the engangement; before knowing that Jeanne was a woman).
2. and Unlike Jeanne, Olmine had no intention of killing anyone (directly).